# TelemetryConfiguration circular dependency with a custom ITelemetryInitializer - Application Insights ASP.NET Core 5.0

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, azure-application-insights

I'm trying to implement a custom `ITelemetryInitializer` (`UserTelemetryInitialiser`) that attaches some user metadata to app insights messages, and I'm getting the following circular dependency.

`UserTelemetryInitialiser` goes to a users cache that depends on `IMemoryCache` as implemented by `Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory.MemoryCache`. `MemoryCache` is then dependent on `ILoggerFactory` (implemented by `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LoggerFactory`) and `LoggerFactory` eventually depends on `TelemetryConfiguration`.

So I have this (shortened) circular chain: `TelemetryConfiguration` -> `UserTelemetryInitialiser` -> `MyUserCache` -> `MemoryCache` -> `LoggerFactory` -> `TelemetryConfiguration`.

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

I'm using ASP.NET Core 5.0 with Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore 2.18.0.

EDIT:
My simplified initializer looks like this (where `IHttpContextAccessor` is used to get the user identity):

```
   public class UserTelemetryInitialiser : ITelemetryInitializer
   {
       private readonly IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor;
       private readonly IMemoryCache cache;

        public UserTelemetryInitialiser(IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor,  IMemoryCache cache)
        {
            this.contextAccessor = contextAccessor;
            this.cache = cache;
        }
        public void Initialize(ITelemetry telemetry)
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why do you need to cache in a telemetry abstraction? What are you caching?

Comment: I've got a cache of my users, and I want to access that cache in the `MyUserTelemetryInitializer` so I can attach the user role to app insights messages (sys admin, super user, etc.)

Comment: I'm not sure but if this works I can post as a well structured improved answer - inject `IServiceProvider` into your class, and use `services.GetRequiredService<IMemoryCache>()` - does that work?

Comment: I have a telemetry initializer which uses that same cache but does not have any problems.  How does the initializer look like?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary with this solution I now seem to have an infinite loop where calling `GetRequiredService` triggers a new `TelemetryClient.Initialize` call which calls my initializer's `Initialize` method, which calls `GetRequiredService`

Comment: @PeterBons I've updated my question to show what the initializer is like (it's a simplified version of the real thing that still exhibits the problem)

Comment: `GetRequiredService` shouldn't trigger anything - can you please edit the Q to show me how you've done it?

Comment: I suppose the whole thing is simply registered as `services.AddSingleton<ITelemetryInitializer, UserTelemetryInitialiser>();` ?

Comment: Your service would be yes - but I mean this: `public UserTelemetryInitialiser(IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor,  IServiceProvider _services)` & then *outside of the constructor* wherever you want to use the cache: `var cache = _services.GetRequiredService<IMemoryCache>();`

Comment: @PeterBons yes that's right

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary thanks but yes that's what I tried, getting the service in the Initialize method

Comment: And what error did you get? Did you get the `IMemoryCache`?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary I'm not getting `IMemoryCache` because when I call `GetRequiredService` in my `Initialize` method, it somehow ends up calling `Initialize` on my initializer again and so it gets stuck in a stack overflow

Comment: How are you calling the `Initialize` method?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary it's getting called by app insights I guess, it's happening right as I start the app: at the top of the call stack is `HostBuilder.Build()`

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm running into the exact same issue with regards to the Initialize method being called infinitely.

Comment: @Fraser: i posted two possible solutions for you in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

### Problem Root

The problem with Injecting `IMemoryCache` into a `ITelemetryInitializer` when using dependency-injection, is, that calling `services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry()` registers a `ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider` for the `LoggerFactory`.

Since the default implementation of `IMemoryCache` (`MemoryCache`) has a dependency on a `ILogger`, and this requires a
`LoggerFactory` which now in turn depends on `ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider` which constructs a `TelemetryClient` and thus depends on all configured `ITelemetryInitializers` ... we now have a circular dependency.

### Solution A (No logging in MemoryCache within the TelemetryInitializer)

if you are okay with not logging messages from `MemoryCache` within your TelemetryInitializer,  you could configure your TelemetryInitializer simply by providing a Setup-method where you construct a `MemoryCache` without a Logger (which defaults to using  a `NullLogger.Instance`):

```cs
            services.AddSingleton<ITelemetryInitializer>(serviceProvider 
                => new MyTelemetryInitializer(new MemoryCache(optionsAccessor: serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IOptions<MemoryCacheOptions>>())));
```

### Solution B (Remove ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider from your logging configuration)

for the off-chance, that logging in MemoryCache is more important to you, than having `warnings` tracked by application insights, you could remove the `ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider` from your LoggerFactory:

```cs
services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();
services.AddSingleton<ITelemetryInitializer, MyTelemetryInitializer>();

//must be called *after* AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry()
services.AddLogging(loggingBuilder =>
            {
                foreach(var aiLoggingProvider in loggingBuilder.Services.Where(p => p.ImplementationType == typeof(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ApplicationInsights.ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider)).ToArray())
                {
                    loggingBuilder.Services.Remove(aiLoggingProvider);
                }
            });
```